# What does the word "nominal" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

(source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliber)

In guns, particularly firearms, caliber (or calibre; sometimes abbreviated as "cal") is the specified **nominal** internal diameter of the gun barrel bore - regardless of how or where the bore is measured and whether the finished bore matches that specification.

One of the synonyms from TFD website is **minimal**:
2. token, small, symbolic, **minimal**, trivial, trifling, insignificant, inconsiderable *The ferries carry bicycles for a nominal charge.*

Does that mean nominal mean minimal here?

Comment: Within accepted limits or tolerances

Comment: [Merriam-Webster, **nominal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominal) definition 3b: *of, being, or relating to a **designated** or **theoretical size** that may vary from the actual : **APPROXIMATE***

Comment: Another typical example of a nominal size is **2x4 lumber**.  It's been a long while since a 2x4 actually measured two inches by four inches.